# Can't use srcCompat for ImageViews in android

Tags: android, imageview, androiddesignsupport

I'm using the Design Support Library 23.2. 
I've added these lines in my build.gradle as my Gradle Plugin is version 1.5

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        generatedDensities = []
    } 

      aaptOptions {  
        additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
      }  
     }
```

as it's specified in [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

But I can't use the srcCompat attribute for my imageview.

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:srcCompat="@drawable/wallpaper"/>
```

where @drawable/wallpaper is a vector resource file

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
<path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M4,4h7V2H4c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v7h2V4zm6,9l-4,5h12l-3,-4 -2.03,2.71L10,13zm7,-4.5c0,-0.83 -0.67,-1.5 -1.5,-1.5S14,7.67 14,8.5s0.67,1.5 1.5,1.5S17,9.33 17,8.5zM20,2h-7v2h7v7h2V4c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2zm0,18h-7v2h7c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2v-7h-2v7zM4,13H2v7c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2h7v-2H4v-7z"/>
```

It says

> Error:(14) No resource identifier found for attribute 'srcCompat' in
>   package 'android'

My Gradle version is 1.5. How can I use srcCompat?

Comment: None of the solutions worked for me. It turns out, the answer is to use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView (ImageView and android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView did NOT work)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

**Don't**

```
android:srcCompat="@drawable/wallpaper"
```

**Do**

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/wallpaper"
```

as it **srcCompat** attribute is actually defined within **AppCompat** library.

**Important** you will need to add appropriate namespace for this.

> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

**Important**

> what you are getting it seems like it is just a lint error that can be
>   ignored. I have tried  and have the same error, but it is working
>   correctly.

you can use `tools:ignore="MissingPrefix"` to avoid seeing this error temporarily.

Comment: But it says Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag Imageview, when I add  app:srcCompat="@drawable/wallpaper".

Comment: you need to add xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  in your xml root tag.

Comment: are you sure using AppCompat library into your app? please post your full xml file

Comment: It says "Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag Imageview"

Comment: please paste your build.gradle file

Comment: Please see my edited answer. Its an lint error. so you can ignore this.

Comment: Ignoring is not a good solution because preview doesn't render the layout

Comment: Yes, agree but we can expect this as bug which would be gradually been resolved in next version of android studio as its still in Beta and not stable.

Comment: and what about using android:background or drawable for textviews? how to use it with vector drawable with this approach?

Comment: I add all these but app crash on runs.

Comment: I'm just wondering, how did you know that we should use `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` and not `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`? Thanks! This fix my problem, but I don't understand how/why :)

Comment: If you still get error after adding `app:srcCompat`, add this line to `build.gradle -> defaultConfig`:
`vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true`
Then synch the gradle

Answer (score 29):

Combining many answers into one answer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="@color/primary">


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/logoImageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/my_logo_vector"
        android:tint="@color/white"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This worked for me. No lint errors. Use `AppCompatImageView`.

Comment: Hey did you do something with build.gradle as well?

Comment: @Solace you need appcompat gradle `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'` (use same version as your compile project)

Comment: But I am using Eclipse :(

Comment: @Solace I am sorry to hear that.

Comment: Does that mean I can't use VectorDrawableCompat in Eclipse?

Comment: @Solace No clue. I do not use eclipse for android development.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Solace I deeply recommend you try Android Studio latest version it's a lot better than Eclipse for Android development

Answer (score 13):

First (in build.gradle)

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Second

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_traffic_black_24dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```

Third

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

Here we go.

Comment: I have all three of those .. the `xmlns` ones properly on the root node for the activity's layout. I get a red underline on the `app:srcCompat` line with the warning:_Unexpected namespace prefix 'app' found for tag ImageButton_

and if I ignore it and install on a device that needs API 19 I get:  `Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{xyz.selfenrichment.robertotomas.homeroast/xyz.selfenrichment.robertotomas.homeroast.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: Error inflating class ImageButton`

Comment: What should a person who is using Eclipse, rather than Android Studio, do?

Answer (score 7):

I just changed:

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/wallpaper"
```

to

```
android:src="@drawable/wallpaper"
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Call `app:srcCompat` instead of `android:srcCompat` .

**Don't**

```
android:srcCompat="@drawable/your_image"
```

**DO**

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/your_image"
```

**Finally**

```
    <ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:srcCompat="@drawable/wallpaper"/>
```

### My gradle version is 1.5

Upgrade your **Gradle version**.

**Solution**

```
Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta2
```

> Vector drawables allow you to replace multiple png assets with a
>   single vector graphic, defined in XML. While previously limited to
>   Lollipop and higher devices, both VectorDrawable and
>   AnimatedVectorDrawable are now available through two new Support
>   Libraries support-vector-drawable and
>   support-animated-vector-drawable.

Add this

```
    // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }
```

**You’ll note this new attribute only exists in the version 2.0 of the Gradle Plugin. If you are using Gradle 1.5 you’ll instead use**

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

Go Through **[Support Vector Drawables](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)**

Comment: it says Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag Imageview, when I add app:srcCompat="@drawable/wallpaper".

Comment: https://medium.com/@chrisbanes/appcompat-v23-2-age-of-the-vectors-91cbafa87c88#.gu1oxadgs

Answer (score 3):

there is multiple things which you have to care about
First of all use:

```
defaultConfig {
            vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        }
```

or

```
vectorDrawables {
        useSupportLibrary = true
    }
```

and Secondly use

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:id="@+id/changeLanguages"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background="@color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_transfer" />
```

Always use  AppCompatImageView or Button because vector image is not supported by Simple ImageView

if all the above methods not worked then use

```
public class App extends Application {

  @Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // Make sure we use vector drawables
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
  }
}
```

If you are using Activity then extend your Activity with AppCompatActivty

```
public final class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {    
  @Override protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using `android:srcCompat`. It should instead by `app:srcCompat` as it is an attribute defined within AppCompat, not within the `android:` namespace.

Answer (score 1):

I know am late but It might help someone else. I was facing the same issue even though I was using **app:SrcCompat**.After spending a lot of time I figured it was due to drawables. My issue simply resolved by moving all drawables from drawable(v21) to simple drawable.

Answer (score 0):

update your gradle plugin to 2.0+

```
// Gradle Plugin 1.5  
android {  
     defaultConfig {  
          generatedDensities = []  
     }  

// This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
     aaptOptions {  
          additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
     }
```

as per google developer's blog guid lines

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html

Answer (score 0):

From, [Android developer site](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html)

This library is now a dependency of the `v7 AppCompat library`, allowing developers and AppCompat to easily use vector drawables.

To use VectorDrawableCompat within an ImageButton or ImageView, **use the app:srcCompat XML attribute or setImageResource() method.**

To keep referencing attribute IDs on API level 20 or lower, add the following appt flag to your build,gradle file:

If you are building with Android Plugin for **Gradle 1.5.0 or lower**, add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Stops the Gradle’s automatic rasterization of vectors
    generatedDensities = []
  }
   // Flag that tells aapt to keep the attribute ids
  aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"
  }
}
```

If you are building with Android Plugin for **Gradle 2.0.0 or higher**, add the following to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

to your layout for it to work. My "app:srcCompat" was highlighted in red until i added it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the picture you are trying to use is PNG format.

Copy the picture.

Go to mipmap on the 1.Project TAB in the android hierarchy.

Click on mipmap once then(On windows ctrl + v ), when you name the photo make sure its lower case letters and no symbols.

The photo should be useable.

Set your image view, (you may have to use a filler color temporarily).

Click on the imageView and then click the srcCompact (the one without the paintbrush and type on @mipmap/"Your pictures name" (This step is in the attributes tab)

That should work!

If you need a Content Description I just used @String/StringPicture