# App works well in android 5.1 and 6.1 but crashes in 4.10(API 16)

Tags: android, android-5.1.1-lollipop, android-4.1-jelly-bean

I am a newbee in the Android development. I am able to make this app work in Android 5.1 and but however when I tried to deploy this app in Android 4.1 it used to crash in the main activity itself. I understood its becuase I used vector images and android 4.1 is not compatible with it. To overcome this I set the code as mentioned below:

```
 // Gradle Plugin 2.0+  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
 }  
You’ll note this new attribute only exists in the version 2.0 of the Gradle Plugin. If you are using Gradle 1.5 you’ll instead use
 // Gradle Plugin 1.5  
 android {  
   defaultConfig {  
     generatedDensities = []  
  }  

  // This is handled for you by the 2.0+ Gradle Plugin  
  aaptOptions {  
    additionalParameters "--no-version-vectors"  
  }  
 }
```

**I am getting this error now**

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:  main                                          java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activityComponentInfo{com.abc.efg.plcapp/com.abc.efg.ghi.MainActivity}:
>   android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37: Error
>   inflating class ImageView
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                                                                                 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #37:
>   Error inflating class ImageView
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129)
>                                                                                    at
>   MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File
>   res/drawable/ic_mood_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020057
>                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1918)
>                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
>                                                                                    at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:120)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:57)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:53)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675)
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
>                                                                                    at
>   MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                                                                                 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
>   1: invalid drawable tag vector
>                                                                                    at
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)
>                                                                                    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
>                                                                                    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1915)
>                                                                                    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601) 
>                                                                                    at android.widget.ImageView.(ImageView.java:120) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:57) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.(AppCompatImageView.java:53) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:963) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1022) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView(LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:675) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:830) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:736) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
>                                                                                    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:267) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:129) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.abc.efg.ghi.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
>                                                                                    at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
>                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
>                                                                                    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
>                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                                                                                    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>       06-28 20:06:42.790 1648-1648/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 1648 SIG: 9

Code file

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    Button btnRegister;
    Button btnRequestLog;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;
    private String android_id;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
       setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
if ( findViewById(R.id.fab) == null)
    {}
        else {

        }
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

        // Buttons
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        btnRequestLog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRequestLog);
```

XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Please help me in debugging this. I am kind of stuck and would need your help.

Comment: Please post your file: res/drawable/ic_mood_24dp.xml

Comment: Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_mood_24dp.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020057

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using vector drawables. On Android 4.x and earlier, this is only supported if you:

- use Android Support Libraries 23.x or later ✓
- enable it in the gradle build file (vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true) ✓
- use `srcCompat` instead of `src` whenever you use `ImageView`

The last item is probably the problem that needs to be fixed.

Comment: Thank you So much for you help Codo... it worked. however when I was trying to add srcCompat it was not allowing me to do so,I could add srcCompat with help of this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645148/cant-use-srccompat-for-imageviews-in-android