# How to use VectorDrawableCompat from the AppCompat library?

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable, android-appcompat

I initially wrote this SSCCE with a `minsdkversion` of `21` (Lollipop), and it worked fine. *But my need is to use a `VectorDrawableCompat` in pre-lollipop.* In the SSCCE, there is an `ImageView` in the XML layout, in which the source of the image is a vector graphic defined in `res/drawable/` directory.

Initially, when `minsdkversion` was set to `21` in manifest, I used `android:src="@drawable/vector_circle"` to set the vector graphic as the source of the image in `ImageView`. This worked fine.

Then I changed `minsdkversion` in manifest file to `11`. I also changed `ImageView`'s `android:src="@drawable/vector_circle"` attribute to `app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_circle"` in XML layout. **But I am getting**

```
Unexpected namespace prefix "app" found for tag ImageView
```

**on `app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_circle"` line. How should I fix this?**

***SSCCE:***

**res/drawable/vector_circle.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:width="465dp"
     android:height="420dp"
     android:viewportHeight="600"
     android:viewportWidth="600" >

    <group>

        <path android:strokeColor="#2196F3"
            android:strokeWidth="2"
            android:pathData="M150,10 L75,200 L225,200 Z" />

    </group>

</vector>
```

**activity_main:**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_circle" /><!-- app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_circle" -->

</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

---

***EDIT:***

I changed `res/layout/activity_main.xml`'s `ImageView` element to

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_circle"
        tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```

I also added `layout-v21/activity_main.xml` to the `res/` directory:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/vector_circle" /><!-- app:srcCompat="@drawable/vector_circle" -->

</FrameLayout>
```

and added the `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to `FrameLayout` element.

**The pre-compilation error went away. But when I run the app on Lollipop device, the vector graphic is drawn perfectly fine, but if I run the app on a pre-lollipop device, the application does not fail, but the vector graphic is not drawn at all.**

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645148/cant-use-srccompat-for-imageviews-in-android)? It might help, check it out and write the result :)

Comment: @Vucko Yes, as you can see, I have used `app:srcCompat`, and not `android:srcCompat`. I have included the `xmlns:app` namespace as well. The only thing which is different is that in their question, they have mentioned that they ave done something with `build.gradle` file. I am using Eclipse, so I didn't do anything of the sort, I just included the AppCompat-v7 library in my project.

Comment: @Vucko Besides, this is not a lint error. It is proper error (with with Eclipse shows red colored undlerline and cross) which makes the project Fail to compile

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that you did almost everything like you should, that's why I cannot help you locate the issue further :D

Comment: @Vucko Well there is some progress. I posted an edit in the question.

Comment: Yes, I can see. Well, I am sincerely sorry that I am of not much use, but when I use vectors, I usually import them via **new->vector asset** and import from a local SVG.

Comment: @Vucko "when I use vectors, I usually import them via new->vector asset and import from a local SVG" I am not getting you. Can you point me to some tutorial which explains this process/method you use?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117482/discussion-between-vucko-and-solace).

Comment: Try to set:  compileSdkVersion 23,  buildToolsVersion '23.0.3' and don't forget about " vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true ".

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do to fix this is use the widget that can handle `app:srcCompat` and that is `AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView`.