# Android ImageView always empty

Tags: android, imageview

I'm developing an Android application and I'm having a very hard time showing a sample image here.

XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.xwaybill.xdriver2.HelpActivity"
android:background="#EAEAEA">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/footerlogo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:elevation="21dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

[See image for result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WJA6.png)

I got the image in all the resolution folder in the resolution. This is not my first application and this one is an update of an old one. Since, I migrate form Android 3 to 6, I'm starting having this king of trouble. I also want to mention that I have the same exact image on an other Activity and it showing correctly.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, in Build.gradle:

```
defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

Second:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/XXXX"
    tools:ignore="MissingPrefix" />
```

Finally:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

This article may helpful for you: [Can't use srcCompat for ImageViews in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645148/cant-use-srccompat-for-imageviews-in-android)

Comment: I already did this for the first activity, base on that article. It's not working here. Thx.