# Android Studio-Image showing in design view but not in emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I am learning android app development.So while I was building a simple app to show two images on the screen,I have used ImageView.The images are displayed in the android studio design screen,but when I am trying to run the app using the genymotion emulator,the screen is just blank.I am not able to see the images.here is the xml file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="showmebioapp.studio.com.showmebio.MainActivity"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/vegeta"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageVegetaId"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageGokuId"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageGokuId"
        android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/goku"
        android:layout_marginBottom="79dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageGokuId"
        android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="62dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> MAIN ACTIVITY.JAVA

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ImageView vegetaImage;
private ImageView gokuImage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    vegetaImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageVegetaId);
    gokuImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageGokuId);
    vegetaImage.setOnClickListener(this);
    gokuImage.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.imageVegetaId:
            Intent vegetaIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
            vegetaIntent.putExtra("vegetaBio","hello from vegeta");
            startActivity(vegetaIntent);
            break;
        case R.id.imageGokuId:
            Intent gokuIntent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,DetailsActivity.class);
            gokuIntent.putExtra("gokuBio","hello from goku");
            startActivity(gokuIntent);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

[image]
   [image]

Please Help me in finding me the solution.

Comment: Do you actually use this layout in your activity? Show your activity's `onCreate()` method.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: @manabreak Yeah I have used it

Comment: @manabreak I have edited my post adding the MainActivity.java code.Please see

Comment: Have you tried using `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat`?

Comment: No I have tried it now it worked thanks!.But can you please tell me why app:src compat did'nt work.Because I have used it in another app it worked.But Why it is not working in this case?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I think it might only work with vector drawables - did you use those in your other app?

Comment: No I have'nt used any vector drawables.

Comment: Ah. Not quite sure then what caused the issue.

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView> using this tag also I am able to see the images in the emulator.Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are using srcCompat instead of using src just like using back goku instead of goku

```
  <ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:src="@drawable/vegeta"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageVegetaId"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageGokuId"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageGokuId"
    android:layout_marginRight="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp" />
```

as it **srcCompat** attribute is actually defined within **AppCompat** library.

**Important** you will need to add appropriate namespace for this.

> xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

**Important**

> what you are getting it seems like it is just a lint error that can be
>   ignored. I have tried  and have the same error, but it is working
>   correctly.[for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645148/cant-use-srccompat-for-imageviews-in-android)

Happy coding :)

Comment: I have used android:src @manabreak suggested it.It worked.Can you tell me why?.Because app:srcCompat worked for my other app.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Just went through this issue for <1 hour - download and try a different emulator and check it. That was my fix after trying the tips mentioned above!