# ImageView not showing in phone but showing in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, imageview

My issue is that, when I add an ImageView using the "Pick a Resource" tool, the image is shown in the layout of the activity in Android Studio. but when I execute it on my phone which is *Huawei Y7 Prime*. It doesn't show at all.

I tried many solutions that are proposed in other questions step by step but any of them didn't seem to work.

1. Tried to use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` instead of `ImageView` but it seems that the android studio doesn't recognize it. I set all steps in  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221986/android-vector-drawable-appsrccompat-not-showing-images)... But -> not working!.
2. I used `android:src` instead of `app:srcCompat` like it says in [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43311760/android-image-not-showing-in-imageview)  -> not working!.
3. I Set a line of code like this `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` in AndroidManifest.xml file in the Application tag -> not working either!.
4. Used `src` instead of `srcCompat` like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39808796/android-studio-image-showing-in-design-view-but-not-in-emulator)

I used a very basic code to set the ImageView

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic" />
```

I Used The LayoutInspector tool to see if the image is showing. I found that it's not.

Please Anyone can help??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `tools:srcCompat`, you should use `android:src`.

The `tools` namespace is used for debug purposes, that's why it's visible in AndroidStudio but not in actual device.

Also, make sure your source uses the valid reference (or one from android). For example:

```
android:src="@drawable/your_image"
```

Comment: Tried it.. but it says : Cannot resolve symbole for `@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic` !

Comment: Like I said, use actual image reference. Don't use `tools` namespace.

Comment: Thank you for your help @waqaslam I understood the thing.