# Whats the different between srcCompat and background in an ImageView/ImageButton

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview

I have an ImageView in a RelativeLayout. The background of the ImageView is empty and the srcCompat is linked to my image in the drawable folder. In the layout Preview everything looks fine but when I test the app in an emulator or real smartphone my ImageView is empty and I can't see the selected Image. When I link the background property to my image in the drawable folder and delete the entry from srcCompat my picture is shown by the app. The problem is I can't scale the image if its set as the background of my ImageView. Can someone help me?
Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Same problem here? Do you have a solution ?

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that `srcCompat`is the actual content of your ImageView. You can, for example set `backgroundColor` to red, and give a drawable to your `srcCompat`. The result will be a red background and the given drawable above it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `src` in place of `srcCompat`.As it srcCompat attribute is actually defined within AppCompat library. [For more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35645148/cant-use-srccompat-for-imageviews-in-android)